# How does React VDOM save unnecessary DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

I have searched quite a lot for understanding this, but I am unable to find the answer. Please do share a link or any study material related.

For reference let’s look at two pieces of code.

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = '<span>clicked</span>';
})
```

And some piece of code in React:

```
const Component = React.memo(() => {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

    return(
       <>
         <button onClick = {() => setClick(true)}>Btn</button>
         {click && <span>clicked</span>}
       </>
    );

});
```

In both cases, the DOM is being manipulated. In both cases, will the browser have to redraw the whole DOM?

If so, what is the point of VDOM? I am reading a lot about VDOM and how it saves all the unnecessary DOM manipulation. But I am a little bit stuck here.

Comment: Might be worth checking out this video. Main points are `Diffing` and `Reconciliation` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7pyEDqBDeE and more on Reconciliation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: The article has a flowchart showing how VDOM works. It helped me to understand. Although the article about VDOM Preact . But react uses most of the concepts also.
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/the-inner-workings-of-virtual-dom-666ee7ad47cf

Answer (score 0):

Virtual DOM is more related to the ways React (and other frontend frameworks on the wild) could handle renders when state changes than to how you can manipulate the DOM directly with JavaScript.

Let's look at your React example:

```
const Component = React.memo(() => {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

    return(
       <>
         <button onClick = {() => setClick(true)}>Btn</button>
         {click && <span>clicked</span>}
       </>
    );

});
```

Before we click the button we would have an HTML that looks somewhat like this:

```
<button onclick="...">Btn</button>
```

But, when we click it the HTML will need to look like this other one:

```
<button onclick="...">Btn</button>
<span>clicked</span>
```

How do we change the first into the second?

The most direct approach would be to just "copy and paste" this target HTML into the parent element and re-render everything (both, the button and the span). This would be something similar to doing `document.getElementById('whole_app_container').innerHTML = newHTML;`. Turns out that there is a more efficient approach, virtual DOM. With virtual DOM you construct a tree for both the old HTML and the new HTML, and then you compare then. This way, instead of re-rendering everything you could see the only change is that we added a span. So, you would use `document.getElementById('whole_app_container').addChild(...)';` and, thus, only update the new children triggering less re-renders. Changing HTML attributes can also be optimized in a similar way.

Take a look at [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for a more technical and accurate explanation.